# Can you please explain to me why the Lower Bound Wildcards does not work in my example?

Tags: java

```
public class aa {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Predicate<? super String> predicate = s -> true;

        Stream<CharSequence> stream1 = Stream.generate(() -> "growl! ");

        boolean b1 = stream1.limit(2).anyMatch(predicate);// Compiler error
    }
}
```

String implements CharSequence; to my knowledge, that means predicate has to accept CharSequence.
But the compiler says that I have to cast my predicate to be like this:

```
boolean b1 = stream1.anyMatch((Predicate<? super CharSequence>) predicate);
```

I don't understand why I have to cast my predicate.
Can you please explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: When using a `Stream<CharSequence>`, the statless method `anyMatch()` will accept an argument of type `Predicate<? super CharSequence>`. Your `predicate` is of type `Predicate<? super String>`, which is not within the bounds of `Predicate<? super CharSequence>`.

Comment: Generics are invariant. `Predicate<String>` is not a `Predicate<CharSequence>`. And the introduction of wildcards does not change that

Comment: FYI the opposite works, i.e. `Predicate<? super CharSequence> predicate` and `Stream<String> stream1`

Comment: @Glains Thank you. It is clear to me now.